# Is it possible to Unmarshall a JSON which has varying field?

Tags: json, api, go

I am tring to get League of Legends champion informations from LOL static database. Link is given below.

[Get info for specific hero](http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.2.1/data/en_US/champion/Aatrox.json)

The problem is that i can only make request by hero names and all JSON responses are different from each other by only one field which is a "main" field; hero name. You can find problematic field as highlighted below:
[image: Aatrox is just a hero from 158 other]

Also tree respresentation:

[image]

My goal is to get all hero informations with iteration by range of known hero names as slice. You can check the code. I need only a couple of fields but the main tag is varies with every new request.

```
func GetHeroInfo(heroName string) *LolHeroInfo {
getUrl := fmt.Sprintf("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.2.1/data/en_US/champion/%s.json", heroName)
fmt.Println(getUrl)
resp, err := http.Get(getUrl)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return nil
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
read, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return nil
}
heroGoverted := LolHeroInfo{}
err = json.Unmarshal(read, &heroGoverted)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("unmarshall failed:", err)
    return nil
}
return &heroGoverted }
```

Struct type LolHeroInfo is structifyed from this link: [mholt's JSON to struct](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/)

You can check JSON response for another hero eg: [JSON response for Annie](http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.2.1/data/en_US/champion/Annie.json) .

Is there any way to make an agnostic struct field/tag for a JSON field. I believe this will be very hard because encoding/json package needs to check for field for particular tag in that JSON but maybe you  encountered this kind of problem before. Creating separate struct for each hero is impossible so i will drop this case if i can't find a solution.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: I'd recommend against containing anonymous types in the type definition. If you ever need to construct even as much as a part of that object manually (e.g. for a test) you will enter a world of hurt.

Comment: custom unmarshaler for `data`. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70928056/17893197

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know it's just a single unknown key, you could just decode into a `map[string]LolHeroInfo` for the `Data` field, then do

```
heroGoverted := LolHeroInfo{}
for _, v := range decoded.Data {
    heroGoverted = v
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve problem, I used @dave 's solution.

I breake main struct into two separate struct. This way varying JSON field eliminated:

```
type LolHeroInfo struct {
Type    string                    `json:"type"`
Format  string                    `json:"format"`
Version string                    `json:"version"`
Data    map[string]HeroInfoStruct `json:"data"`
```

}

[image: Second struct]

```
heroInfo := lib.GetHeroInfo(lolHeroes[i])
    for _, v := range heroInfo.Data { //unmarshalled to first struct
        a := lib.HeroInfoStruct{} //data field; second struct
        a = v
        fmt.Println(a.Lore)// now i can reach to every field that i need
    }
```